# Dart2js : Is it possible to start Root Isolate from Javascript?

Tags: requirejs, dart, dart-isolates, dart2js

I have an application compiled in dart2js (Dart SDK version **0.6.13**.0_r25630)
and I'd like to load it with RequireJS everytime I need.

First of all, **thanks God for wrapper function in compiled javascript**, but in my case is not enough :(

I use **requirejs** to load a **dart2js** application

```
 require(["application.dart"], function () {});
```

but i would like to handle when to start the application. for example on click event.

```
require(["jQuery","application.dart"], function (jQuery,$) {
        jQuery(element).click(function(){
           $.startRootIsolate($.main$closure);
        })

});
```

**I hacked the compiled Javascript, but i'd like to know if it's possible in native way.**

in application.dart.js I wrapped the function in a AMD module

```
(function (factory) {
if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
    // AMD. Register as anonymous module.
    define([],function(){
        return factory();
    } );
} else {
    // Browser globals.
    factory();
}
})(function($) {...})
```

then I return $ Object

```
return $;
```

and finally i commented this line of code where i found

```
$.startRootIsolate($.main$closure);
```

Thanks everyone

marco

Answer (score 0):

I doubt this is possible without hacking at the code as you have. However, Dart 1.6 added support for deferred loading which might give you an alternative way of doing what you need?

http://news.dartlang.org/2014/08/dart-16-adds-support-for-deferred.html